# Keycloak - Current language code in theme

Tags: themes, keycloak, freemarker

I would like to output the two letter language code (f.e. `en`) of the current language in the freemaker template of the login theme.

I already tried `${locale.current}`, but this only outputs the name of the current language and not the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have enabled Internationalization for themes use:

```
${locale.currentLanguageTag}
```

`${locale.currentLanguageTag}` => `en`

`${locale.current}` => `English`

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm that this works, for example as `<html lang="${locale.currentLanguageTag}">`

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy way to check in the template if that is defined? So the page won't fail when internationalization is turned off.